# Wifi doesn't work but Skype does (and it's not like the one case you already solved)

Tags: wifi

So. I select a wifi network. Get into safari and int wont load the main page. But I can make calls in skype and with perfect comunication with the caller. (Wifi works for skype) but when I do all the steps you told somebody to do (go to the network preferences. Then "advanced" go to the DNS. And select one of thise numbers (8.8.8.8) (they are not grey for me, they're black) then Ok and then Apply, safari would still not load and skype would kee working. What can I do?

Comment: We don't know how to help you unless you narrow down the setup. Are you on a PC or a Mac or an iOS device? What version of OS is running. Can you name one specific web site that isn't working? Are you able to run the networking assistant on the computer/device?

Answer (score 2):

To find the hosts file, open Finder and, in Finder’s menu bar, select Go > Go to Folder. In the box, type the following location and press Return.

```
/private/etc/hosts
```

That will show you the Host file.

Double click on it and you will see:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

Yours has to be exactly as this, nothing more or less.

If it is different, let me know so we will fix that.